# lrbox doesn't work in math mode

Tags: math-mode, environments, fbox

I'm trying to create a custom environment, using which I'd be able to create a box around a certain part of an equation in math mode. I have tried to use `lrbox` to make it possible to use `fbox`. Unfortunately using `lrbox` causes strange errors about various missing symbols (removing the `fbox` part results in exactly the same errors).

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% For important formulas
\newsavebox{\formulabox}
\newenvironment{formula}{\begin{lrbox}{\formulabox}}{\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\formulabox}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{displaymath}
        \left.
        \begin{array}{lcl}
            q & \sim & t\\
            q & \sim & I
        \end{array}
        \right\}
        \implies
        \begin{formula}
            I=\frac{q}{t}
        \end{formula}
    \end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Errors (explanations for insertions removed for brevity):

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.20 ^^I^^I^^II=\frac{q}{t}

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\frac  #1#2->{\begingroup #1\endgroup \@@over #2}

l.20 ^^I^^I^^II=\frac{q}{t}

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.21 ^^I^^I\end{formula}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 ^^I^^I\end{formula}
```

Mockup of desired result:

[image: mockup of an equation, which has an equation with a box around it]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: `lrbox` is like `\mbox` and sets its content in text mode so you need `$` to get back to math, but simpler is to use the `\boxed` command from `amsmath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: picture showing correct desired output]

`lrbox` is like `\mbox` and sets its content in text mode so you need `$` to get back to math, but it's simpler to use the `\boxed` command from amsmath (which is loaded by mathtools).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
    \begin{displaymath}
        \left.
        \begin{array}{lcl}
            q & \sim & t\\
            q & \sim & I
        \end{array}
        \right\}
        \implies
        \boxed{
            I=\frac{q}{t}
        }
    \end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @tambre it doesn't matter, but why did you change the image? the one I posted looked more or less the same and was generated by the posted code?

Comment: I didn't change the image. I only added alt text for it, so people with screenreaders know what's on the picture.